# Facebook Like Count different for iframe vs JS SDK on same page! Why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

### **Problem :**

When we switched from the Facebook iFrame like button code to the HTML5 JS SDK button, the like counts for our pages got completely reset! (400+ likes went to 0 in some cases). We've waited close to a week, as well as pushed links through the linter and there have been no increase to the previous values.

---

### **Verification :**

When we run both types of buttons on the pages together, the iframe still shows the larger / original like count. [Test link (will only have 3 buttons for the next ~12 hours)](http://www.team-bhp.com/forum/indian-car-scene/117538-2012-budget-indian-car-scene-all-you-need-know.html)

Screenshot : [3 Like buttons on the same page (iframe, JS-SDK w/ url encoding & JS-SDK standard)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uujrB.png)

---

### **The Like Button Code :**

I thought perhaps it was due to url encoding, so the difference between the 2nd and 3rd buttons is url encoding on the web address. The first button is the iframe.

```
    <td><iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.team-bhp.com%2Fforum%2Fshowthread.php?t=$thread[threadid]&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=verdana&amp;height=21&amp;appId=106794169377106" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </td>

    <td align="left" valign="middle" style="width: 90px">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.team-bhp.com%2Fforum%2Fshowthread.php?t=$thread[threadid]" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="90" data-show-faces="false" data-font="tahoma"></div>
    </td>

    <td align="left" valign="middle" style="width: 90px">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.team-bhp.com/forum/showthread.php?t=$thread[threadid]" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="90" data-show-faces="false" data-font="tahoma"></div>
    </td>
```

---

### **Meta tags :**

Meta tags show up fine in the facebook linter/debugger (though "og:image", "og:description" and "og:url" aren't explicitly specified)

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The 2012 Budget &amp; the Indian Car Scene : All you need to know - Team-BHP" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Team-BHP.com" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1504944662" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="106794169377106" />
```

---

### **HELP!**

Why is this happening??

Is the iFrame also showing likes accumulated on facebook itself?

Has the "app_id" suddenly come into effect only for the JS-SDK button?

Any insight would be appreciated!!

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at the source of the test link you provided, and the iframe src has this value:

```
//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.team-bhp.com%2Fforum%2Findian-car-scene%2F117538-2012-budget-indian-car-scene-all-you-need-know.html
```

As oppose to the other two plugins which have

```
http://www.team-bhp.com/forum/showthread.php?t=117538
or
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.team-bhp.com%2Fforum%2Fshowthread.php?t=117538
```

as their *data-href*.

Looks like the iframe uses the *pretty url* while the other two are using the short verion, and since you are using different urls you are getting different results.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that Nitzan! Though if you see the actual source code from the template posted in my reply, all 3 buttons use the "showthread.php?t=$thread[threadid]" code. So how come the iframe URL is showing up as a pretty url on the live site?

Comment: I have no idea why you get the long url instead of the short one in the iframe. You need to check exactly where that changes. I doubt that it's done by the facebook plugin, since I looked at the code of your site and not the updated dom, because of that it looks like that's the source your php script produced.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a place to start at Nitzan. I'll look into this. I'd upvote your answer, but i don't have the permission to do that at the moment! :)